# Linq list of enumerators seem to be recreated when accessed through linq

Tags: c#, linq, enumerator

I am trying to understand what goes wrong in the following piece of code.

```
    var signals = new List<List<double>>
    {
        new List<double> {1, 2, 3},
        new List<double> {2, 3, 4},
    };

    var enumerators = signals.Select(l => l.GetEnumerator()).ToList();

    if (enumerators.All(enumerator => enumerator.MoveNext()))
    {
        var cummulative = enumerators.Sum(enumerator => enumerator.Current);
    }
```

Why are both enumerators pointing to the current value 0? I would expect both would point to the first number in the list, which would be 1 and 2 respectively.

Each time I access the enumerator via linq it seems to restart. Why?

Comment: Because the enumerator is before the first position in the collection and current is undefined.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ why is it undefined? I called the MoveNext in the if statement

Comment: This is what happens when you use linq to mutate data. Things never go as you'd expect. Don't do it, linq isn't meant to be used like this.

Comment: @InBetween whoa! That's quite a statement too :). How is linq meant to be used? PS: I am not mutating anything yet, I am simply getting values through iterators.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List<IEnumerator>.All(e => e.MoveNext()) doesn't move my enumerators on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537567/listienumerator-alle-e-movenext-doesnt-move-my-enumerators-on)

Comment: Yes, you are mutating. What do you think  `e => e.MoveNext()` supposedly does? Your false expectations are based upon `All` *mutating* the enumerators and that the changes are permanent in the underlying data which is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code as per below

```
var enumerators = signals.Select(l => l.GetEnumerator() as IEnumerator<double>).ToList();
```

As per this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23537567/listienumerator-alle-e-movenext-doesnt-move-my-enumerators-on)

> It is because the enumerator of List is a struct whereas the enumerator of Array is a class.
>
> So when you call Enumerable.All with the struct, copy of enumerator is made and passed as a parameter to Func since structs are copied by value. So e.MoveNext is called on the copy, not the original.

Comment: That works indeed. So what black magic goes down here under the hood?

Comment: @bas see my edit

Answer (score 1):

According to [`List<T>.GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8)

> Initially, the enumerator is positioned before the first element in
>   the collection. At this position, the `Current` property is undefined.
>   Therefore, you must call the `MoveNext` method to advance the enumerator
>   to the first element of the collection before reading the value of
>   `Current`.

To get an expected behavior and sum the value you can write the following

```cs
var cumulative = 0d;
foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
{
    if (enumerator.MoveNext())
        cumulative += enumerator.Current;
}
```

`All` just return the `bool` value, it doesn't change the source sequence or its items.

> Each time I access the enumerator via linq it seems to restart. Why?

`Enumerator<T>` is a `struct` and value type, it's not a class. Every time when you modify it, you modify the copy, the element in source `enumerators` list remains unchanged and enumerator positioned before the first element

Comment: Sorry I might have asked the question unclear. In the example above, I DO call MoveNext on all enumerators. Then, when accessing the enumerator again (from what I would expect the same object) the `Current` property is zero

Comment: @bas no, `All` doesn't work that way. `Any` just determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition; it doesn't change the collection...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ any? Not using .Any

Comment: Why does the `.All` just return the value? It executed the method `Enumerator.MoveNext()`. I don't understand how that effect simply never happened

Comment: @bas `Enumerator<T>` is a value type and struct, you modify the copy, which doesn't affect the element in source list

Comment: Right, you and Lucifer nailed it. Thx